# passing state from child to parent causes react component lifecycle to restart

Tags: reactjs

In my project I'm filling out an input in my child SearchBar component.

Upon submitting the form I want to change the state of the searchQuery property in my parent component and use that state for an api call.

I passed down a handleSubmit function from the parent (App) component to the child (SearchBar) component and pass in the input value to the function. Then in my handleSubmit function on the App component I'm able to change state to the value I want.

My expectation was that since I used setState this would cause the render function to run again followed by componentDidMount.

However, the entire React Component Lifecycle has restarted so this.state.searchQuery is always reset to its initial value of an empty string and I therefore always search for an empty string.

Why are all the functions of the React component lifecycle starting over? How can I fix this problem so I'm able to pass in the proper value to my api call in componentDidMount?

My code is below:

Parent Component (App)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar.js"

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: [],
      planets: [],
      searchQuery: ''
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    console.log('in constructor. this.state.searchQuery is: ', this.state.searchQuery) //empty string
  }

  handleSubmit(event, value) {
    console.log('handle submit is called. value is: ', value);
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: value
    }, ()=> {
      console.log('this.state.searchQuery is:', this.state.searchQuery); //the value I type in
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this.state.searchQuery is: ', this.state.searchQuery) //empty string
    //make api call
   api.fetchPeople(this.state.searchQuery).then((results)=> {
     //do stuff
   }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('in render. this.state.searchQuery is: ', this.state.searchQuery) //empty string
    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='logo'>
        </div>
        <SearchBar submit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child Component (SearchBar)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.props.submit(event, this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='search-bar'>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} placeholder='Search Your Destiny' />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My expectation was that since I used setState this would cause the render function to run again followed by componentDidMount.

The handleSubmit function in the parent (App) sets the state of the component and then triggers the componentWillUpdate lifecycle function and not the componentDidMount function.

componentDidMount triggers only once when the component is mounted:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I can see my state change in componentDidUpdate. However afterwards the entire component lifecycle restarts again. I suspect its because pressing enter causes a refresh of the page that I need to prevent. I tried putting event.preventDefault() in componentDidUpdate, but I wasn't able to pass event there and I'm not sure if that's the right idea.

Comment: you shoud use event.preventDefault() in the handleSubmit in the SearchBar component. This will prevent the page from reloading.